# MYSQL checking if a record exists with the specified child-records

Tags: mysql

Okay, let's say I have a table called rooms:
It only has one column: ID
I also have another table called items_in_rooms with columns:
roomId, itemName, itemColor

Whenever a room-record is inserted a bunch of records is also inserted into items_in_rooms linked to the row-record, specifying what items are in that room.

The problem is that when a room-record along with its items, I need to first verify if a room with those exact items don't already exist.
How can this be done?

One way of course would be to first fetch all room-records along with all their items then look through them until it has been verified there isn't already an exact copy in the database and then do insertion if it's unique.
But this sounds a bit ineffective to me, especially as the tables grows very large so I was hoping there's a way to have MYSQL do the checking.

One way I came up with was to do something like this:

```
SELECT roomId FROM(
        SELECT rooms.id roomId, GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT_WS(',',itemName,itemColor) ORDER BY itemName,itemColor  SEPARATOR '/'
        ) roomContents
        FROM items_in_rooms
        JOIN rooms ON roomId=rooms.id
        WHERE snapshotDate='$dateString'
        GROUP BY roomId
    ) concatenatedRoomContents
    WHERE roomContents='bed,white/carpet,red/chair,brown'
```

Essentially this will make MYSQL concatenate each room into a string, then compare them to the "input-string" in the WHERE-clause. Obviously the input-string would have to be ordered the same way as how MYSQL orders the rows before concatenating (itemName,itemColor).

While this worked for be it felt very dirty. Also, it initially caused some problems when I had added a decimal-field as MYSQL always includes every decimal-digit when stringifying so 1 for instance could be "1.000" 
while PHP which I'm using by default stringifies it to "1". I solved this using number_format() making it include the right amount of decimal-digits.
Now I've noticed I've got some duplicates in the table again so there's some other gotcha I need to find, but I was just wondering if there's maybe a more clever way?

Comment: Write a query that selects all relevant records individually (`WHERE foo IN('abc', 'xyz', ...)`), group by room id, and count the number of records - and then see if that count matches the number of values you have in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand...

Comment: Say you are interested in finding all rooms that have the items A, B and C. Then you select all records where the itemName column has either of those singular values (`IN('A', 'B', 'C')`), group by the room id, and check the count of those grouped records - if that count matches the number if items you are looking for - 3 - then you have found a room that has those three items. (If it is supposed to be a match only if it has _exactly_ those three items, and no other items - then you need to check the count of _all_ item record for that room as well.)

Comment: Alright, I worked out how it can be done and posted an answer. And I think that is what you meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done. The following query returns the id of the room if such a room exists(it has exactly those items, no more, no less).

```
SELECT roomId FROM (
    SELECT roomId,count(*) numMatchedItems
    FROM items_in_rooms WHERE (itemName,itemColor)
    IN (('bed','white'),('carpet','red'),('chair','brown'))
    GROUP BY roomId
) matches
WHERE  numMatchedItems=3
```

Thanks,  CBroe.

Comment: No, this would not only return rooms that have _exactly_ those items, but also rooms that have all the required items, plus additional ones. If you want only rooms that have only _exactly_ those items, then you need to check if the count of all records for that room id is also 3, and not greater.

Comment: It does check for that with the final row in the query. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You are only counting the rows here, that matched the WHERE clause. So if a room has an additional record for an additional item, the count from above query would still be 3 (because three rows with items matching what is listed in the IN operator where found) - but that room has more than _just_ those three items.

Comment: Oh, duh. Apparently wasn't thinking straight. Now fixed. Thanks again!